# Maven ear contains old version of war file

Tags: java, maven, war, ear

I'm creating an ear package using maven which will contain a war file of the module. When I run mvn clean install from the ear pom folder location, maven just copies the existing war file into the ear. What I want is maven to create a fresh war file and package it up into the ear. So I have to first run mvn clean install for the war and then for the ear.
 Below is the pom.xml for the ear. Is there anything missing from the pom?

```
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <artifactId>abc-module-ear</artifactId>
  <packaging>ear</packaging>
  <name>${project.artifactId}</name>

    <properties>
        <parent.basedir>${basedir}/../..</parent.basedir>
    </properties>

  <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
            <artifactId>abc-module</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
            <type>war</type>
        </dependency>   
  </dependencies>
  <parent>
    <groupId>com.nab.cmservices</groupId>
    <artifactId>cmservices-base</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.16-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </parent>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <!-- Configuration for "abc-module.ear" -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-ear-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <version>5</version>
                    <displayName>abc-module-ear1</displayName>
                    <defaultLibBundleDir>lib</defaultLibBundleDir>
                    <modules>
                        <webModule>
                            <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
                            <artifactId>abc-module</artifactId>
                            <uri>abc-module.war</uri>
                            <contextRoot>/abcservices-web</contextRoot>
                        </webModule>
                    </modules>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Just run `mvn clean install` from the parent.

Comment: @Tunaki This is the parent pom as I wrote it to generate ear file. When I run     "mvn clean install" it just copies the existing war file inside the ear without generating a fresh war. What I want is that it should create a new war and then copy it into ear.

Comment: No the parent pom is `cmservices-base`. It is the one declaring `abc-module-ear` and `abc-module-war` as modules.

Comment: @Tunaki Thanks for your comment, so if I want to create an ear using the above pom without running the parent so what should I do? If I make ear-module the parent of war module then it complains that the parent packaging should be pom not ear.

Comment: Which is expected yes. Why don't you want to build the parent? It's what it is for: encapsulate the build of multiple modules. Otherwise, you will need to build the WAR then the EAR manually everytime.

Comment: @Tunaki So you are saying that I cant build the EAR (and a new version of WAR inside) just by "mvn clean install" on above EAR pom?

Comment: Yes, that is what I'm saying.